# 1.Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets

Tags: c++, qt, web

Well, I was trying to use QWebView. As I learned from the internet, I should, and also this line `webkitwidgets` in `.pro` file after `QT +=`. So I added it and get this error:

> `Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets`

I know that a lot of people already asked about this error, but most of the answers were to install `libqt5webkit5-dev` using this command line: `sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev`.

The problem is, that I am on Windows, not on Linux, so this can't be useful for me.

**The weird thing is**, that I have `Qt5WebKitWidgets.dll` and `Qt5WebKit.dll` in `C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin`, so I suppose, that I have everything I need to use QWebView and to add this line `QT += webkitwidgets` without getting any errors.

Also, I learned that WebKitWidgets is no longer supported after QT 5.0 and newer(or something like that), and I should use QtWebEngine, but I don't understand how to use it in Qt Widgets Application with QWebView.

Answer (score 3):

You're mixing up Qt Creator (an IDE) and Qt — the development toolkit itself. It absolutely doesn't matter what's bundled with Qt Creator — whatever is there is used solely by Qt Creator since it is also built using Qt.

You need to look in your Qt's installation directory, under `mkspecs/modules`. Each module has a `.pri` file. You should see both `qt_lib_webkit.pri` and `qt_lib_webkitwidgets.pri`. If you don't, that would mean that the modules weren't built for the Qt that you're using. The modules folder is where `qmake` looks for Qt module definitions.

If you're using a prebuilt recent version of Qt, it's likely that it is built with WebKit turned off. The workaround would be to go to a previous minor version (say 5.4 instead of 5.5), or to build Qt yourself.

Comment: I have those two files in: **C:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\mkspecs\modules**
and **C:\Qt\5.5\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\modules** but dont have in:
**C:\Qt\5.5\android_armv7\mkspecs\modules** and **C:\Qt\5.5\winphone_x86\mkspecs\modules**

I need them in last two directories. 
Should I try other version of Qt?

Comment: @LeonidManieiev Well, are you building for android or windows phone? If not, then you're OK. Finally, are you using Qt with mingw or with msvc2013? Under Qt Creator, are you building your project with the correct Qt kit?

Comment: I am building for android and windows phone. I am using Qt with GCC 4.9 for Android and MSVC2013 with windows phone. About last question, I dont understand what are you mean.

Comment: "I simply copy those files" You cannot do that, since you don't own these folders. They are a part of Qt distribution. Stop modifying stuff that's not yours to modify. It's a very bad habit. "It seems to work" Are you sure that your project builds and runs correctly? The Qt that you've installed simply does not seem to support webkit under android and windows phone, that's all, unless it's a packaging bug of some sort where the `.pri` files are somehow not installed, even if they should be. Feel free to check the bug database about that.

Comment: Yeah I already realize, that just coping files was bad idea. So, finally, what should I do, try another version of Qt?

Comment: @LeonidManieiev Check what prebuilt Qt versions provide the webkit module for Android and Windows Phone, and use them instead - just download latest 5.4 and/or 5.3 and see there. Perhaps the module is merely deprecated in 5.5 and thus not included in the prebuilt version of Qt 5.5. You should, eventually, build your own Qt, so that might be a good moment to do so. It should still work under 5.5 AFAIK.

Comment: @LeonidManieiev If you don't need to speicifcally use the `QWebView class, use `QWebEngineView` from the `webenginewidgets` module.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Kuba Ober's answer, I got it to work by copying the webkit and webkitwidgets pri files from a previous installation, 5.5.

`~/Qt/5.5/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/`

Answer (score 0):

> The weird thing is, that I have Qt5WebKitWidgets.dll and Qt5WebKit.dll in C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin, so I suppose, that I have everything I need to use QWebView and to add this line QT += webkitwidgets without getting any errors.

Thats because windows dlls must be on the path or on the base path of the app, is just the way of windows of doing things. You can see that if you install qtcreator on windows, the app will be without dlls on the lib folder. Everything will be on the bin folder